# Oracle sql Inner join first record in right table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

my question is this:

I have two tables such as this:

```
username | portname | symbol | shares
---------+----------+--------+-------
phil     | test     | APL    | 214
---------+----------+--------+--------
```

It has more records, but that's just an example. Then I have another table such as this, that has multiple records per symbol

```
symbol | high | low | timestamp
-------+------+-----+-----------
APL    | 200  | 20  | *timestamp object
APL    | 400  | 34  | *timestamp object
```

I want a table to be returned where I join the two, but only the first row from the second table is joined so something like this is returned:

```
symbol | high | low | timestamp
-------+------+-----+----------
APL    | 400  | 34  | *timestamp object
```

So only one record from the right table is matched. I've tried alot of things but haven't gotten anything to work with group by's or distinct.

Thanks!

Comment: How is the 1st row defined? What the order?

Comment: by timestamp, so the latest added row in the second table!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.symbol, t3.high, t3.low, t3.timestamp 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (
      SELECT inn.* 
      FROM (SELECT t2.*, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY timestamp DESC)) As Rank 
            FROM Table2 t2) inn 
      WHERE inn.Rank=1
     ) t3
     ON t1.symbol = t3.symbol;
```

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d169/31)

Comment: the line "FROM Table1 t1" what is the name of the actual table? is t1 just a naming shortcut?

Comment: @phouse512: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sql.htm#BJEHEBBC